# Bootstrap form isnt' responsive/collapsible

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've designed a contact page form in bootstrap, I would like to know with what scaffolding I should wrap the form to make it collapsible.

**How and where do I wrap the form element to make it fully responsive?**

> **[Full Fiddle Attached](https://jsfiddle.net/erezt/urs2p3fa/)**

```
.video_contain{
    position: absolute;


    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: none !important;
}

video {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -100;
/*    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;*/
    cursor: none !important;

}


/*form steps and itzuv*/
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    /*Image only BG fallback*/

    /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
    background:
            linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    padding:20px;
    background-color: rgba(83, 107, 166, 0.36);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none;
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
    background: #27AE60;
    color: white;
}
```

Thank!

Comment: try like this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want the form to look like at the different screen sizes.  Right now it's staying small and centered on large screens, and overflowing on small screens. If I assume you mostly want to keep it from overflowing on small screens, what do you want it to look like when it is smaller?

The simplest place to start is to change width to max-width on your `#msform` element:  https://jsfiddle.net/1Lbz5shs/1/

(Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lbz5shs/2/)

```
#msform {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

instead of

```
#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

It looks like it will need some other tweaks, most likely in a media query like this:

```
@media (max-width:400px) {
  /* styles for small screens here */ 
  /* stack the 'step indicators' on small screens */
#progressbar li:after {content:none;}
  #progressbar li {
    clear:both;
    float:none;
    margin:20px auto;
  }
}
```

Also...can't help but mention `cursor: none !important;` ...all I can say is please don't! There's no reason to make your users guess where their mouse is, and on a touch device, there's not a cursor anyway...if you really want to hide it, maybe put it on some kind of timeout so that it disappears when the mouse is still for a second or two, and show it again when it moves again?

Comment: What a  fully invested answer! Thanks!
max-width solved one issue, now I guess the media queries solve the collapsing parts? When I check the page on console with mobile emulator (both chrome & FF) the form elements do not collapse - does the media query wrap the form or the whole css? How do you set the HTML scaffolding elements accordingly? Please help with setting the CSS queries and HTML elemts and I'll set it as your answer bud, thx!

Comment: still not especially clear what you mean...if you're wanting to stack the steps indicators instead of floating them, I've added an example of that and an updated fiddle.  If you want to further resize particular elements, simply add the additional styles specific to small screens inside the media query as demonstrated for the steps indicators.  the contents of the media query will apply globally like your normal CSS, except they will only be applied if the viewport is narrower than 400px wide.